# Please exclude version tags from title bar

Tags: feature-request, tags

I mean questions like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/166796/16495) - there is nothing wrong with it being tagged [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7), but this isn't great:

[image: Screenshot]

The same will appear in Google results etc. I believe [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) would be more relevant for this question. And that's the case for pretty much all questions with version tags.

I know it might be hard and would need network-wide hack, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Would it be possible to exclude 6/7/8 tags from being used in the title generation?

Comment: @digital possible, yes. Will they? Can't say.